# Where is the img location?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

All , Say you have a code in a `View` like this.

```
<img src='@Url.Action("GetCaptchaImg")' alt='' />
```

and of course there is an `Action` named `GetCaptchaImg` in the controller which return a `FileContentResult` to View.

After open this view in FireFox. I found the Html code is

```
<img alt="" src="/Controllername/GetCaptchaImg" />
```

the `src` is not the real physical path . So My question is what is the real physical path of this `img`, How can I change the image by Ajax call to an `Action`? Hope you can help me . thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an ajax call to the actionresult and from that return the name of the image and onsuccess of your ajax call change the image
Alternatively you can  do this thing, which i've implemented in my project
Make your HTML form like  this

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionResult", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "ImgForm", @enctype = "multipart/form-data", name = "ImgForm", target = "UploadTarget" }))
{
}
```

Make an iframe as target of your form

```
 <iframe id="UploadTarget" name="UploadTarget" onload="UploadImage_Complete();" style="position: absolute;
        left: -999em; top: -999em;"></iframe>
```

Your upload control

Then upload the Image and Show it on your form

```
 function UploadImage() {       
            $("#ImgForm").submit(); //form id
        }

        function UploadImage_Complete() {
            try {
                //Check to see if this is the first load of the iFrame
                if (isFirstLoad == true) {
                    isFirstLoad = false;
                    return;
                }

                //Reset the image form so the file won't get uploaded again
                document.getElementById("ImgForm").reset();
                //Grab the content of the textarea we named jsonResult .  This shold be loaded into 
                //the hidden iFrame.
                var newImg = $.parseJSON($("#UploadTarget").contents().find("#jsonResult")[0].innerHTML);

                if (newImg.IsValid) {
                    document.getElementById("dp").src = newImg.ImagePath;
                    document.getElementById('profile-pic').src = newImg.ThumbnailPath;
                    document.getElementById("change").style.display = "block";                          

                }

                // If there was an error, display it to the user
                if (newImg.IsValid == false) {
                    alert(newImg.Message);
                    return;
                }                      
            }
            catch (e) {
            }
        }
```

Your Action will look like this

```
 public WrappedJsonResult ChangeImage(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
}
```

and your WrappedJsonResult class will look likes

```
public class WrappedJsonResult : JsonResult
    {

        public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
        {
            context.HttpContext.Response.Write("<html><body><textarea id=\"jsonResult\" name=\"jsonResult\">");
            base.ExecuteResult(context);
            context.HttpContext.Response.Write("</textarea></body></html>");
            context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "text/html";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Firstly thanks your help. But I found an easier way to make it .please review [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1823616.aspx/1), Your solution is absolutely a good one . I had marked it as an answer. thanks.